# TFS Pending Change shows phantom change

Tags: tfs

I've got an odd situation.  After adding a couple of files to a TFS project, they show up in the source control browser with a pending change of 'edit'.  If I attempt to check in any pending changes, TFS informs me that there are no pending changes, yet the source control browser clearly shows them with a Pending Change as 'edit'.  I've tried the command line and any other trick I could come up, all to no avail.

Anyone else ever seen this and if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You might have them checked-out , but the files are the same.

You can verify this by doing a compare of the server file to your local work space.

To remove the edit status simply run 'undo pending changes' .

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that may be causing this.

1. Source Control Explorer will show both the changes you have in your current workspace and changes that are pended in other workspaces.  Is there a red check mark glyph next to the item in Source Control Explorer?  If not, this item is checked out in another workspace.
2. It is possible for the pending changes window to have one workspace active while the source control explorer has another workspace active.  When this is the case, they won't show the same view for pending changes.  Each of the two windows have a workspace picker at the top of them.  Make sure they are on the same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and the way I fixed it was by recreating the phantom folder by letting Visual Studio download the same project copy again. Then in the pending changes, I did a right click/undo changes, then removed the link from the workspace. It never appeared again.